# How to highlight cells in an arbitary selection which match to a value in an array?

Tags: excel, vba

So for example, say my array is [32,43,92,99] ("hard coded" into the VBA code, don't need to worry about any inputs) and then in an excel sheet I highlight some rectangular grid of cells numbered 1-100. Would it be possible to cycle through the array and highlight the corresponding cells with those values in the sheet? In this case highlighting the cells reading 32, 43, 92, 99.

```
Sub readClipboard()
  Dim DataObj As New MSForms.DataObject
  Dim S As String
  DataObj.GetFromClipboard
  S = DataObj.GetText
  S = Application.Clean(S)
  S = Application.Trim(S)
  S = Split(S)
End Sub
```

So I'd want to then match up this array S with a selection, then highlight the cells which have values that match to values in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to accomplish this. This is assuming you've selected/highlighted the range that has the values you are going to match. This just sets the color of the cell to an ugly gray.

```
Sub highlightfromarray()
    S = Array(1, 5, 10, 23, 38)

    'Capture user range selection to a variable
    Dim userRange As Range
    Set userRange = Selection

    'VAriable for found range
    Dim foundRange As Range

    'Loop through array
    For Each numItem In S
        'Using Range.Find() method, find each item and highlight
        Set foundRange = userRange.Find(numItem)
        If Not foundRange Is Nothing Then foundRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Wouldn't you go the other way - loop through the range and try to find each cell value within the array? **EDIT:** Well I guess based on the OP's description of no duplicates in the range, this would work.

Comment: 1. It sounds like the range is bigger than the array, so looping the smaller of the two will be more efficient. 2. There is no `Array.Find()` method so one would have to loop the array upon each cell in the range which would be double taxing. | This has 5 iterations, the other method would have 200.

Comment: Right. I was considering the possibility of duplicates in the range, at which point only one `Find` call per member of the array wouldn't work. But you could call `Match` on the array right, to avoid looping the array in the other method?

Comment: Oh I see! Yes that makes sense. That would make it quite a bit uglier.

Comment: Right - so your answer is appropriate given the OP's specifications.